# Remove stylesheets css from a Python Panel HTML file

Tags: python, tabs, panel

I am trying to create simple HTML reports using Panel and Plotly and push them in an app, however the app refuses the reports because of some external links.

The following simple code shows you these unwanted links.

```
import panel as pn
tabs = pn.Column()
file_name = "my_file.html"
tabs.save(file_name)
```

Produces a HTML file containing these links

```
  <title>Panel</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/notyf@3/notyf.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/dataframe.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/json.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/alerts.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/loading.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/markdown.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/card.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/debugger.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/css/widgets.css" type="text/css" />
        <style>
```

How can I remove them ?
Why would I need them ?
I have looked at the doc of Panel but didn't find any relevant parameters that might help me to remove thse...

Answer (score 0):

> I would consider using BeautifulSoup for this task.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for m in soup.find_all('link'):
m.replaceWithChildren()
print soup
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but I realized it also changes the design of the HTML pages.
Is there a way for me to actually update the URL to point a local repo ?

Comment: no need then to remove them , otherwise u can just download those files and import them from local